# Notification manager not working with alarmManager

Tags: android

I am trying to use alarm manager to show notification after 5 sec. I have tried many sites but was not able to understand please give a simple example for explaining how to use alarm manager and connect notification with it.

I am newbie.

this is function i used to set alarm and I am not getting notification after 5 secs actually not at all not in emulator nor in android mobile. If put code to create notififcation with a button pressing that is working great.

```
public void setAlarm(View view)
{

Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReciver.class);

Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

tv.setText("completed");
}
```

and this class to make it work

```
public class AlertReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
createNotification(context,"times Up", "5 SEcond has passed", "Alert");

}

public void createNotification(Context context,String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert){

PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ne)
        .setContentTitle(msg)
        .setTicker(msgAlert)
        .setContentText(msgText);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);

mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


}
```

this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.deepaksingh.goinnotifying" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MoreInfoNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_more_info_notification" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

</application>
```

Comment: did you rigister your broadcast class in manifest?

Comment: yes did add it in manifest too

Comment: Add logs to your receiver logs to see if it triggered at all

Comment: and add to question your manifest file

Comment: okay i am updating the manifest

Comment: the thing is it wont wake alarm up no matter what i have changed time to 0 also used setExact also setWindows no matter what i use it wont wake up the alarm and shift controll to the AlertReciver. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havn't set permission for wake:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

ANd you didn't register your recevier.Here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MoreInfoNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_more_info_notification" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlertReciver "/>

</application>
```

Comment: i just have to write <activity android:name=".AlertReciver" android:label="@string/app_name" </activity>    right

Comment: No. It receiver not Activity. is need just the name of the class. you can put the whole name with packages to be sure

Comment: ANd you not need label to it